# How can I conditionally multi-thread and update variables at the same time?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, inter-process-communicat, juce

My code is:

```
while (DAQ is ON) {
do stuff on vars;
if(f(vars) > thr)
update vars;
}
```

The if condition will be triggered only occasionally and will update all the variables used in the earlier section of the while loop. The overall loop is usually running in real time (as needed) but falls behind when the if condition also needs to be run. How can I run the if condition in a separate thread? It can take all the time it needs, it's okay if the update happens after a delay. I just want the rest of the while loop to run in real time and for the vars to get updated whenever the "if" thread gets done.

Context: C++/JUCE framework, real time signal processing.

Comment: Is it the `f(vars)` that is the problem, or the update?  If you replaced `f(vars)` with making a copy of `vars`, would that be fast enough?

Comment: No the update steps inside the if are the problem. When the if condition runs, it doubles the time taken by the loop. The update involves lots of matrix and vector operations. "f(vars)" was just notation. I mean to say that a parameter derived from the vars is thresholded.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that you have at least 2 cores to work with here.  Otherwise, multithreading won't help you much, if at all.  I'm using the C++11 multithreading semantics here, so you'll to enable the C++11 language specs in your compiler:

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

condition_variable cv;
mutex mtx;
bool ready = false;

void update_vars() {
    while( true ) {
        // Get a unique lock on the mutex
        unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);
        // Wait on the condition variable
        while( !ready ) cv.await( mtx );
        // When we get here, the condition variable has been triggered and we hold the mutex
        // Do non-threadsafe stuff
        ready = false;
        // Do threadsafe stuff
    }
}

void do_stuff() {
    while( true ) {
        // Do stuff on vars
        if ( f(vars) ) {
            // Lock the mutex associated with the condition variable
            unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx); 
            // Let the other thread know we're ready for it
            ready = true;
            // and signal the condition variable
            cv.signal_all();
        }
        while( ready ) {
            // Active wait while update_vars does non-threadsafe stuff
        }
    }      
}


int main() {
    thread t( update_vars );
    do_stuff()
}
```

What the above code snippet does is creates a secondary thread running update vars, which will hang around and wait until the main thread (running do_stuff) signals it through the condition variable.

PS, you could probably also do this with futures, but I've not worked with those enough to answer based on those.

Comment: Assuming the update thread needs to access some data produced by the "main" thread, more will be required won't it?

Comment: Yakk, this is a framework.  There may be additional synchronization required, depending upon the semantics of do_stuff() and update_vars().  For example, update_vars() may need to copy the vars to a temporary area, manipulate them, signal the main thread that it's ready to update the vars, wait for the main thread to indicate it's ready for the new information, copy the information back, and let the main thread know the new information is ready.

Comment: Ken, if everything update_vars() does is non-threadsafe then the situation will end up much like before, right? do_stuff() will have to wait for all of update_vars() to finish.

For my application, data is coming in real time, and do_stuff() needs to run again and again. I would like do_stuff() to be able to simply start the update_vars() and not wait. Later calls to do_stuff() may then check if update_vars() is done and the updated variables may be copied over.